# Multithreading android application

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've two threads in my android application one adds speed values every 1/2 a second and the other one gets the average from this array list to reduce fluctuations the problem is only one thread is starting and i don't know why. Here is the code:

```
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (flag) {
                isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
                if(isConnected)
                {
                    gps.getLocation();
                    time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    latitude_temp = gps.getLatitude();
                    longitude_temp = gps.getLongitude();

                    if (!initial_position.flag)
                    {
                        double distance_m = gps.location.distanceTo(initial_position.location);
                        double distance_km = gps.calculateDistance(initial_position);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Diff between gps locations in meters:" + Double.toString(distance_m)
                                + " in km:" + Double.toString(distance_km));
                        if (distance_m >= 10.0) {
                            average = false;
                            storeLocation(vehicle_id, latitude_temp, longitude_temp, time2);
                            double time_s = (time2 - time1);
                            double time_hr = time_s / 3600;
                            double speed3 = (gps.location.getSpeed() * 3600) / 1000;
                            speed = averageSpeed();
                            speed1 = (distance_km) / (time_hr);
                            double speed2 = (distance_m * 3600) / (time_s * 1000);
                            storeSpeed(vehicle_id, speed3, time2);
                            storeSpeed(vehicle_id, speed, time2);
                            storeSpeed(vehicle_id, speed1, time2);
                            storeSpeed(vehicle_id, speed2, time2);
                            time1 = time2;
                            initial_position.location = new Location(gps.location);
                            speeds.clear();
                            average = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        storeLocation(vehicle_id, latitude_temp, longitude_temp, time2); /*added*/
                        initial_position.flag = false;
                        initial_position.location = new Location(gps.location); /*added*/
                        initial_position.latitude = latitude_temp;
                        initial_position.longitude = longitude_temp;
                        time1 = time2;
                    }
            }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            boolean isConnected1 = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            if (isConnected1)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "runnable r1 is starting");
                while (average)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "runnable r1 is in the loop");
                    gps_temp.getLocation();
                    if (gps_temp.location.hasSpeed())
                    {
                        double s = (gps_temp.location.getSpeed()*3600)/1000; 
                        speeds.add(s);
                        Log.i(TAG, "adding speed");
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread myThread1 = new Thread(r1);
    myThread1.start();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(r);
    myThread.start();
```

Comment: Check whether the Thread has actually started (and hasn't simply exited because of a failed if statement)

Comment: How is `flag` declared in the first runnable, and what is its value initially?

Comment: What is the value of flag and the content of the method isConnectedOrConnecting?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of `isConnected` at the start of both threads. Try to put it outside the both and debug.
May be one thread exited because of the value of `isConnected` set in in other thread.